# Differences from logistic regression and mixed effects logistic regression - rounding error or conceptual mistake?

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model, binomial-distribution, random-effects-model

I'm a bit confused. To my understanding, the standard logistic regression should be equivalent to a mixed effect logistic regression where the statistical unit is defined as random effect - but I found the results of the two analysis to be different.

As example, let's say that I have an experiment with 20 participants. To each participant I ask x questions, and their answer is scored either  as either "right" or "wrong".

I simulated the dataset with:

`data0 = cbind(data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 40, replace=TRUE), nrow = 20, byrow = TRUE)), rep(c('a', 'b'), each=10))
names(data0) = c('s','f','c')`

Let's say that the column `s` has the number of right answers, the column `f` has the number of wrong answer, and the column `c` represents a between-subject experimental condition. The subjects are organized per rows.

To test the effect of `c` I can write:

`anova(glm ( cbind( s, f) ~ 1, data = data0, family = binomial), glm ( cbind( s, f) ~ 1 + c, data = data0, family = binomial), test="Chisq")`

which gives me:

`Model 1: cbind(s, f) ~ 1
Model 2: cbind(s, f) ~ 1 + c
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
1        19     49.144
2        18     42.978  1   6.1659  0.01302 *`

So I tried to model the same data with a logistic mixed effect model.

First I converted it to a long format with:

`data1=NULL
for (i in 1 : nrow( data0) ) {
tt = c(rep(1, data0$s[i]), rep(0, data0$f[i]))
t = cbind(tt, rep(i, length(tt)), rep(data0$c[i], length(tt)))
data1 = rbind( data1, t)
}
data1 = data.frame(data1)
names(data1) = c("r","s", "c")
data1$s = factor(data1$s)
data1$c = factor(data1$c)`

Where `s` is the subject ID. Then I tested the effect of `c` with:

`library(lme4)
anova(glmer( r ~ 1 + ( 1| s), data = data1, family = binomial), glmer( r ~ 1 + c + ( 1| s), data = data1, family = binomial), test="Chisq")`

Now the same analysis gives me a different result!

`glmer(r ~ 1 + (1 | s), data = data1, family = binomial): r ~ 1 + (1 | s)
glmer(r ~ 1 + c + (1 | s), data = data1, family = binomial): r ~ 1 + c + (1 | s)
                                                            Df    AIC    BIC
glmer(r ~ 1 + (1 | s), data = data1, family = binomial)      2 290.72 297.45
glmer(r ~ 1 + c + (1 | s), data = data1, family = binomial)  3 289.97 300.07
                                                             logLik deviance
glmer(r ~ 1 + (1 | s), data = data1, family = binomial)     -143.36   286.72
glmer(r ~ 1 + c + (1 | s), data = data1, family = binomial) -141.98   283.97
                                                             Chisq Chi Df
glmer(r ~ 1 + (1 | s), data = data1, family = binomial)
glmer(r ~ 1 + c + (1 | s), data = data1, family = binomial) 2.7548      1
                                                            Pr(>Chisq)
glmer(r ~ 1 + (1 | s), data = data1, family = binomial)
glmer(r ~ 1 + c + (1 | s), data = data1, family = binomial)    0.09696 .`

Is it because of rounding errors in the implementation of the mathematical functions, or there is some fundamental concept I'm missing here?

PS: the results of the two analys can be closer that in the case I reported - I cherry picked an extreme example for the sake of a clear explanation.